# "Ticket failed to send" to Zendesk

Tags: ios, swift3, zendesk, zendesk-app

I am trying to integrate Zendesk feedback view in my iOS application. I am able to open the Zendesk window as well but when I try to send feedback to Zendesk, it fails with the message "Ticket failed to send". Below are the steps I did :

1. Initialise the Zendesk SDK in the appdelegate :

   ZDKConfig.instance().initialize(withAppId: "APPID",zendeskUrl: "https://sumeet07.zendesk.com",clientId: "mobile_sdk_client_CLIENTID")
2. And then I used below code to show Zendesk Feedback form :

   ZDKRequests.presentRequestCreation(with: rootViewController)

   It shows the feedback form but when I try to submit the feedback, It shows the error.

[image: Please see the screenshot]

May be the format of question I ask is not good but may be you can understand what exactly I am asking.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the following lines in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions,

`let identity = ZDKAnonymousIdentity() 
ZDKConfig.instance().userIdentity = identity`

and also make sure AppId, zendeskUrl and clientId same as like in Zendesk.

Comment: Thanks for the help, can you tell me if we can send some user data to their server or not (like name, email, dob etc)?

Comment: No, I think it's not possible using this we can only send the user manual feedback.